# Magento 2 Add Group Title and its own Tabs in Customer Admin edit view

Tags: magento-2.1

We need to show Separate group title and Tabs under it in Customer Admin edit view like attached.

[image]

We can see new tabs under 'CUSTOMER INFORMATION' Group if we do like this

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form">
            <block class="[Modulegroup]\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\Companydetails" name="customer_edit_tab_company_details">
                <action method="setTabLabel">
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Company Details</argument>
                    <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="number">10</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

in **app/code/[Modulegroup]/Customer/view/adminhtml/layout/customer_index_edit.xml**

We need to show this new tabs also as a separate group and its sub tabs. How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at :

```
module-customer/view/adminhtml/layout/customer_index_edit.xml
```

This line in particular :

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\View\PersonalInfo" name="personal_info" template="tab/view/personal_info.phtml"/>
```

You should be able to make your own block class in your module like this. And add it to your xml in customer_index_edit.xml

Shouldn't be difficult from there.

Comment: thats for to show its tab content , my need is completely different. I need to show new tabs under new tab group